# "Throw" concept in Corona SDK

Tags: file, sdk, lua, coronasdk

Alright, I am creating an app where I have already created the touch and drag effect. I don't know how to code the part where the user lets go of the object and it goes flying, hence the "throw."

```
local body = event.target
local phase = event.phase
local stage = display.getCurrentStage()
---
if event.phase == "began" then
    --begin focus
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( self, event.id)
    self.isFocus = true
    self.markX = self.x    -- store x location of object
    self.markY = self.y    -- store y location of object
    physics.addBody(happy)

elseif self.isFocus then
    if event.phase == "moved" then
        physics.addBody(happy)
        -- drag touch object

        local x = (event.x - event.xStart) + self.markX
        local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + self.markY
        self.x, self.y = x, y    -- move object based on calculations above

    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        -- end focus
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( self, nil) 
        self.isFocus = false

    end
end 

return true
```

Once again, I am trying to get the user to be able to throw the object instead of just dragging it. Also, if anyone can help with the touch and hold timer that would make the object go away and respawn then it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably compute the velocity at release: compute the touch position (x1,y1) at touch begin phase and the touch position (x2, y2) at touch end phase, and the time between the two: you then set your object's linear velocity to this (it is a 2D vector) via `object.setLinearVelocity()`. If the body is non-static, this will set it in motion. The motion will depend on whether it is dynamic or kinematic. If dynamic, the velocity will be set then it will change depending on external forces applied to the object (like gravity). Example:

```
local startTouchMove = 0

....

local function touchListener(event)

    if event.phase == "began" then
        ...
        self.markX = event.x    -- store x location of object
        self.markY = event.y    -- store y location of object
        startTouchMove = system.timer()
        ...

    elseif self.isFocus then
        if event.phase == "moved" then
            ...

        elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            -- set the instantaneous velocity based on touch motion
            local dt = system.timer() - startTouchMove 
            if dt ~= 0 then                  
                local velX = ( event.x - self.markX ) / dt
                local velY = ( event.y - self.markY ) / dt
                yourObject:setLinearVelocity(velX, velY)        
            end
        end
    end 
end
```